# How to escape the special char in SAX parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I am parsing the xml file below:

```
    <description>
    <p>
    <a href="http://news.yahoo.com/jessica-chastain-talks-princess-diana-biopic-  164102608.html">
    <img src="http://l3.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/zD3Iwxezk8JVGQwhow7y4Q--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Reuters/2011-11-07T171906Z_01_BTRE7A61C3Y00_RTROPTP_2_FILM-US-JESSICACHASTAIN.JPG" 
         alt="photo" 
         align="left" 
         title="Actress Chastain poses for photographers as she arrives on the "Wilde Salome" red carpet at the 68th Venice Film Festival" border="0" />
    </a>NEW YORK (TheWrap.com) - Jessica Chastain may not win Oscar gold this year, but it appears she will wear a crown.
    </p>
    <br clear="all"/>
    </description>
```

I am using SAX parser and trying to get the data inside the **img** tag, title attribute. But because of the special char **"Wild Salome"** in the text i am getting ExpatParser exception. 
Could you please let me know how this can be solved?

Comment: This XML file is not a correct XML file. The quotes should be escaped to &quot;. It's not the SAX parsing that should be modified, but the program which generates the XML.

Comment: How the quotes can be escaped?

Answer (score 1):

The XML is invalid. Attribute value should not contain quotes (`"`). The program that generated it should replace the inner `"` characters with `&quot;`.

If you print the `&quot;` to a webpage, the browser will automatically show `"`-character on its place.

Comment: I am getting the content from the web and writing it to an xml file.

Comment: Before you write it to xml file you should escape the quotes.