# SAX parser getting error while parsing special character " : "

Tags: android

```
    <media:group>
       <media:content type="video/mp4"   
                      url="http://cdn2.junctiontv.net/dmv/roku/ChiroDiniTumiJeAmar2997fps800kbpsForIPTV.mp4" 
                      bitrate="800" 
                      duration="8100"/>
    </media:group>
    <media:thumbnail 
            url="http://cdn2.junctiontv.net/dmv/images/ChiroDiniTumiJeAmar158x204.png"/>
```

I am trying to parse this xml using SAX Parser. But am getting error due to : in the tags. However if I replace remove : ie, change    to      its working fine.     But problem is ,if I do this, am getting error in url as : is removed after http.

any solution?????????

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046898/how-to-escape-the-special-char-in-sax-parsing

Comment: Just don't remove : when it's inside "" ?

Comment: @dimetil I followed your link. Still not able to make any change. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an appropriate code. Adding this code to any SAX Parser code, xml containing http://  and https://  both can be parsed .

```
       String text10=text9.replaceAll(":", "");                 //text9 is any valid  url with http:// or https://  or both

        String text11="",text12="",text13="",text14="";

        if(text10.contains("http//"))
        {
        text14=text10.replaceAll("http//", "http://");

        }

        if(text10.contains("https//"))
        {
         text14=text10.replaceAll("https//", "https://");

        }

        if(text10.contains("https//") && (text10.contains("http//")))
        {
            if(text10.contains("http//"))
            {
            text13=text10.replaceAll("http//", "http://");
            }
            if(text13.contains("https//"))
            {
             text14=text13.replaceAll("https//", "https://");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("This is demo text     " + text14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SAXparder, use

```
android.util.Xml.parse(InputStream,Xml.Encoding.ISO_8859_1, DefaultHandler);
```

to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to do it.....in a round away process. It works fine if code contains only http://

```
  String text2=text1.replaceAll(":", "");
  String text3=text2.replaceAll("http", "http:");
```

Adding these two lines to my code,makes everything go fine.

Comment: What then happens if the original url started with https:  ?

Comment: I can just add another extra line of code                            String text4=text3.replaceAll("https", "https:");       it will work fine.

Comment: By which time, I think, your https will have become http:s - try again!

Comment: @paulkayuk check my last answer.its working now. Only a bit of checking has been added to previous code.